# OpenGL Instanced Rendering with multiple attributes

Tags: c++, opengl

So I'm quite new to opengl and am currently learning about instanced rendering. I am trying to render 3 triangles with diffrent positions and colors but can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
GLfloat verts[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, +0.5f,
     0.0f, -0.5f
};

GLuint vertexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

GLfloat xOffsets[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
GLuint offsetsBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &offsetsBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetsBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(xOffsets), xOffsets, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);

unsigned int colors[] = { 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xff00ff00 };
GLuint colorID;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);

GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
GLuint indexArrayBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexArrayBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexArrayBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in float offset;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 color;

out vec4 col;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x + offset, position.y, 0, 1);
    col = color;
}
```

fragment:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;
in vec4 col;

void main()
{
    color = col;
}
```

this is how I render:

```
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, 3);
```

Here's how it looks:
[image: Here's how it looks]

As you can see the triangles are in the right position, but the colors are wrong. The first triangle should be blue and the other two should be green. But here it seems like 1 vertex in every triangle is blue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);` Which line is this statement in? More to the point, how many times does this line appear?

Comment: 2 times for the 2 buffers that should only advance 1 index for every instance

Comment: And should the line be *identical* in both cases?

Comment: Well that's pretty much my question. How should I make so only the first triangle is blue

Comment: Oh wait i got it know. They shouldn't be identical. Thanks